# merging collections grouped multiple times

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-7, laravel-collection

I have a collection grouped (multiple times) like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1883 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    57082 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1885 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        "07-2021" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1863 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            343 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1864 ▼
              #items: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have another collection that could have same values or not, and I need to merge these 2 collections with merged elements.

I tried with this, without success (I lose first "group"):

```
$fstCollection = $fstCollection->mapWithKeys(function ($items, $key) use ($sndCollection) {
    return $sndCollection->get($key) ? $items->merge($sndCollection->get($key)) : $items;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm expecting your are loosing the key, by using `mapWithKeys()` wrong, in general that method is used, by returning an associative array, representing the key to map to and the value.

So changing the closure logic to the following, will keep the first group.

```
$collection = $sndCollection->get($key) ? $items->merge($sndCollection->get($key)) : $items;
return [$key => $collection];
```

Alternatively, just using `map()` will solve your problem, `map()` preserves the keys.

```
$fstCollection = $fstCollection->map(function ($items, $key) use ($sndCollection) {
    return $sndCollection->get($key) ? $items->merge($sndCollection->get($key)) : $items;
});
```